# Golang one-legged / two-legged oauth 1.0a authentication

Tags: curl, go, oauth, authorization, signature

I am looking for a library to help me authenticate with a service via oauth 1.0a using one-legged authentication. I only have a `consumerKey`, `consumerSecret` and `resource url`.

Examples are available in curl, PHP and Python. I am trying to authenticate with GoLang.

```
curl
-X GET
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-H 'Authorization: OAuth realm="https://example.com",oauth_consumer_key="1234-5678-91011",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1424789327",oauth_nonce="abcde",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="3iwWBq%2FHaBcDl9Q1o%2BjAc%2BKz8J%2FE%3D"'
https://example.com
```

php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Guzzle\Http\Client;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Oauth\OauthPlugin;

$client = new Client('https://example.com');
$oauth = new OauthPlugin(array(
    'consumer_key'    => '1234-5648-9101',
    'consumer_secret' => 'abcde',
));
$client->addSubscriber($oauth);

$response = $client->get('/')->send();
echo $response->getBody();
```

Python

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

key = '1234-5648-9101'
secret = 'abcde'
example = OAuth1Session(key, client_secret=secret)
url = 'https://example.com'
r = example.get(url)
print r._content
```

I have looked at many oauth libraries in Golang.

https://github.com/mrjones/oauth, requires: `RequestTokenUrl`, `AccessTokenUrl`, `AuthorizeTokenUrl` and `callback url`.

http://godoc.org/github.com/nhjk/oauth, requires: a `tokenKey` and `tokenSecret` as well as the `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret`.

Is there a library I can use which will allow me to authenticate with the service just as easily as php and python examples above? If i can use one of libraries above, could somebody provide a code snippet example? Anything I try just returns unauthorized responses.

Comment: as you have a worked `curl`, why not to compose HTTP request rather than using libraries?

Answer (score -1):

Golang has a different aproach for frameworks, for one reason, you do not need them. You can easyily set the header of the response with the standard http package. When you get the hang of it, you realize that you are dealing with first class objects, which is what those other language frameworks are trying to implement.

Something like this function

```
  func saveHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // allow cross domain AJAX requests
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
}
```